# What does a plus cells & gems icon on the world map mean?

Tags: dead-cells

During a run with 2 Boss Stem Cells enabled, I noticed something odd on the World Map screen. The box for the Ossuary biome had icons of cells, gems, and a plus sign over it. When I died and started a new run, the icon was no longer on the map.

What does it mean when a biome is covered by cell and gem icons on the World Map?

[image: world map screen, gem icons on Ossuary]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the **incentivized biome bonus**:

[image]

According to [Dead Cells wiki](https://deadcells.fandom.com/wiki/Currency#Biome_Incentive):

> A biome incentive is a mechanic where less visited biomes will start to get a bonus to dropped cells and gold. For cells this is a 25% chance for a golden-colored cell being dropped from any enemy, even those which didn't drop a cell. For gold, there is 10% chance for an enemy to drop a gem. The bonus starts appearing when the next selection of biomes you can enter from the current biome have been visited a combined total of 15 times. This only includes visited biomes and at least two of them have to be have been visited. If there is only one available exit out of the current biome, Biome Incentive does not activate.